# Postgres: conditional ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the table below: ([here's a db-fiddle with this example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nVZp5EagiiEgqPYNLvQnKd/0))

```
id   primary_sort   record_id   record_sort  alt_sort
1    2              1           11           100
2    2              2           10           101
3    3              1           12           108
4    3              1           13           107
5    3              2           14           105
6    1              2           15           109
```

I'd like to sort this according to `primary_sort` first. If equal, the next sort field depends on the value of `record_id`: if two rows has the same `record_id`, then sort them by `record_sort`. Otherwise, sort them by `alt_sort`.
I think the query should look something like this:

```sql
select * from example
order by 
  primary_sort,
  case
    when [this_row].record_id = [other_row].record_id
    then record_sort
    else alt_sort
  end
;
```

Expected output:

```
id   primary_sort   record_id   record_sort  alt_sort
6    1              2           15           109
1    2              1           11           100
2    2              2           10           101
5    3              2           14           105
3    3              1           12           108
4    3              1           13           107
```

Here's some pseudocode in Java, showing my intent:

```java
int compareTo(Example other) {
    if (this.primary_sort != other.primary_sort)
    {
        return this.primary_sort.compareTo(other.primary_sort);
    }
    else if (this.record_id == other.record_id)
    {
        return this.record_sort.compareTo(other.record_sort);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.alt_sort.compareTo(other.alt_sort);
    }
}
```

(this is a minimal, reproducible example. Similar SO questions I've found on conditional `order by` are not applicable, because my condition is based on values in both rows (i.e. `[this_row].record_id = [other_row].record_id`))

Comment: (1) All record ids seem to be duplicated, so your logic seems irrelevant.  (2) I don't see how id "5" rises to the fourth position.

Comment: *if two rows has the same record_id, then sort **them** by record_sort* - How this should be merged with other rows? I mean how shall they be positioned relative to other non duplicated records and to other duplicated records?

Comment: @GordonLinoff (1) some rows have `record_id` 1, others have `record_id` 2? (2) id5 has `primary_sort` 3, so is after id6, id1, id2. id5 `record_id` is different from id3 and id4, so when comparing with these, is should sort by `primary_sort` first, then `alt_sort`. id5's `primary_sort` is equal to id3 and id4, but its `alt_sort` is lower than id3 and id4's `alt_sort`, so it comes before those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you *describe* using window functions.  Something like this:

```
select *
from example e
order by primary_sort,
         (case when count(*) over (partition by primary_sort, record_id) > 1 then record_sort
          end) nulls last,
         alt_sort;
```

This does not return the results you specify.  But some variation is probably what you intend.

Comment: perfect, thank you. I changed `nulls last` to `nulls first` to get what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select * from example
order by primary_sort, 
 case when count(*) over (partition by primary_sort, record_id) > 1
      then record_sort else record_id end, alt_sort;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nVZp5EagiiEgqPYNLvQnKd/0)